# Pandas HDFStore: changing dtype of indexes

Tags: python, types, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

**Does there exist a way of controlling the data type that is used for storing indexes of data frames when using [HDFStore.append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore.append.html)?**

It seems pandas indexes are always stored with 64bits in the hdf5 file. I would like to increase storage efficiency and reduce the size of the index columns.

I have a unique 3 column multi index and saving them as uint64 indexes is an enormous waste of space in my application:

Given the following data frame

```
In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]: indA              int32
indB              int16
indC              int8
data              float32
dtype: object
```

simply setting `df.set_index(['indA', 'indB', 'indC'])` before `HDFStore.append` results in `indA`, `indB` and `indC` being stored as `Int64Col` in the hdf5 file.

Not setting a pandas index and specifying pytables data columns instead:

```
store.append('mytable', df, data_columns=['indA', 'indB', 'indB'])
```

`indA`, `indB` and `indC` are stored with their original dtypes, however an additional `Int64Col` is stored in the hdf5 file.

This does not really help: by storing in the original dtypes I am saving/conserving 56 bits for the three `ind` columns. The additional (superfluous) index column however costs 64 bits...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one. Data columns provide the searching capability and provide dtype preservation. Index storage is pretty fixed at the moment.

Providing an option to store the index is an open issue, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8319). I have done a bit of work on it, but its not high priority ATM. Welcome to have you take a look.

The usual answer to wanting to shrink storage space is to use compression. You seem to be jumping thru a lot of hoops to save a relatively small amount of storage, but that's my2c.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Jeff. It appears I was getting carried away trying to optimize storage efficiency: After getting about 50% savings by moving from float64 to float32 for my data columns, I was on a roll... You are right that getting rid of the additional int64 index is not really worth it: I constructed a pytables hdf5 with the structure I was looking for. Compared to a HDFStore hdf5 with indexes as data columns, the saving is only about 2%. (Both bzip2 compressed.) - Clearly not worth the hassle. It appears that compression works exceedingly well on the added int64 index.